# "Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns ['']"—but I'd prefer [] instead

Tags: python

I'm splitting a string using:

```
my_string.split(',')
```

Sometimes the string is empty, which returns `['']`.

My use-case is such that it would be more convenient to receive an empty list. In my application, an empty string is equivalent to no items. `['']`, however, is a list with one item, `''`.

Is there a way I can get around this without conditional or additional logic? I've got a dictionary key assignment that's like:

```
d = {
    'key': map(lambda x: x.strip(), my_string.split(',')),
}
```

It would be cool to keep it  this way, all directly at the key assignment.

Comment: Obviously you'll need _some_ extra logic

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension is faster and more concise that using map

```
d = {
    'key': [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',') if x],
}
```

Additionally your code will work in Python3 where `map` no longer returns a list

Here are a couple of options for the case Matt mentioned in the comments. Choose the one that best suits your purpose

```
>>> my_string = 'foo,,,bar'
>>> [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',') if x]
['foo', 'bar']
>>> [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',') if my_string]
['foo', '', '', 'bar']
```

a more explicit way to write the second alternative is

```
>>> [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',')] if my_string else []
['foo', '', '', 'bar']
```

Comment: If `my_string` is `'foo,,,bar'`, this logically different from the original.

Comment: @MattBall, `if x`  could be replaced by `if my_string` depending on the reequired behaviour in that case

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can get around this without conditional or additional logic?

No. How else would you write code that conveys that you want such behavior? That said, to get identically equivalent behavior, except turning `''` into `[]`:

```
d = {
    'key': [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',')] if my_string else []
}
```

Comment: +1 for addressing "conditional or additional logic". I thought maybe there was a variant of `split` i was missing.

Comment: Isn't that the same as `'key': [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',') if my_string]`?

Comment: @Kenosis no, cf. my comment earlier: _"If `my_string` is `'foo,,,bar'`, this logically different from the original."_

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using filter()

```
filter( lambda x: len(x) > 0 , map(lambda x: x.strip(), my_string.split(',')) )
```

Comment: Can't you use `None` in place of `lambda x: len(x) > 0`?